# XPath expression to select all nodes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I would like to find all `<Field />` nodes (that may be arbitrarily nested) inside a given XmlNode.

If do something like this:

```
foreach(XmlNode n in node.SelectNodes('//Field'))...
```

This returns all  nodes in the *entire* document, not all  nodes under `node`.

Is this how XPath is supposed to work? I looked at some documents and it seems like the `//Node` query should be scoped to whatever node it's invoked at.

Is there any other technique to select all nodes with a given name that are under a specific node?

Comment: Have you considered using LINQ to XML? It's much easier to work with than XPath.

Answer (score 7):

If you use `'//Field'` it's absolut from the root of the document. To search relative to the current node, just use `'.//Field'`.

Answer (score 1):

try to use `SelecteSingleNode()`

Answer (score 1):

Use `./Field`.

- `.//` Means descendants, which includes children of children (and so forth).
- `./` Means direct children.

If a XPath starts with a `/` it becomes relative to the root of the document; to make it relative to your own node start it with `./`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `//` because otherwise it search among all the document irrelatively to the root node.

```
node.SelectNodes("Field")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use simple linq query like this:

```
var techLeads = (from value in element.Descendants ("Manager")
where value.Attribute ("Name").Value == "Mgr1"
select value).Descendants("TechLead");
```

Sample Xml:

> ```
> <Employees>
>  <Manager Name="Mgr1">
>   <TechLead Name="TL1" />
>   <TechLead Name="TL2" />
>  </Manager>
> </Employees>
> ```